# How can one create a conditional github pull request template?

Tags: github, pull-request

I'd like the pull request template to not be applied to my username whenever I open a PR.

Currently to create a template you'll add the template to a `.github/PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE.md` file.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/using-query-parameters-to-create-a-pull-request), you can use a different URL query param when creating your PRs:

> `template` -- `https://github.com/octo-org/octo-repo/compare/main...my-branch?quick_pull=1&template=issue_template.md` creates a pull request with a template in the pull request body. The `template` query parameter works with templates stored in a `PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE` subdirectory within the root, `docs/` or `.github/` directory in a repository. For more information, see "[Using templates to encourage useful issues and pull requests](https://docs.github.com/en/communities/using-templates-to-encourage-useful-issues-and-pull-requests)."

If you use the [`gh pr create` CLI](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_create) there's a `-T, --template <file>` option for your scripts.